# Is "Remember about "doing something" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm currently busy with writing work instructions for work and I'm wondering if the sentence below is correct grammatically:

> Remember about putting the documents back to the....

Can "*Remember about*" doing something be used instead of for example "*Don't forget to put the documents back to the...*"?

Answer (score 1):

It's not idiomatic to say *remember about* in this context.  If this is an imperative, the way to phrase it is **Remember to...**

For example,

> [Remember to plant your peanuts on land suitable for them.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modern_School_Store/mzFJAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22remember%20to%22&pg=RA1-PA73&printsec=frontcover)

*Remember about* is more often used when we discuss recollecting facts about an event or an object.

> [what do you remember about Stalin's death?](https://books.google.com/books?id=kuS_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22remember%20about%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxupX0ivHvAhWTbc0KHbnUAT4Q6AEwAHoECAIQAg)

> [I don't remember about the girls.](https://books.google.com/books?id=tLjoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT9354&dq=%22don%27t%20remember%20about%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHraSOi_HvAhUDCs0KHSfGDTMQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg)

Comment: If it's *not* an "imperative" utterance - as in the question *[Do you] remember putting the documents back?* - we wouldn't *normally* include the preposition "about". But it [does sometimes occur](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22do+you+remember+about+going%22+-%22what+do+you%22), and I wouldn't say it's actually *ungrammatical* - just "not idiomatically common".